# Prove the Topologist's Sine Curve is Not Locally Connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Many questions have been asked about the local connectedness of the Topologist's Sine curve, but here is my confusion:

If the topological space is the subspace $\bar S$, then shouldn't every neighborhood of a given point $x$ be the INTERSECTION of some open set in $\Bbb R^2$ with $\bar S$, instead of a ball of $x$ in $\Bbb R^2$?

If so, then isn't it true that every neighborhood of $x$ is itself connected, hence every point is locally connected, and that makes the Topologist's Sine curve locally connected?

Please help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That is the definition of the open sets in the subspace topology, yes.

Comment: Almost. A neighborhood of a point $x$ (in $\overline S$) is a subset of $\overline S$ that *contains* a set $O\subset\overline S$ such that $x\in O$ and that $O=O^*\cap\overline S$ for some open subset $O^*$ of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Your reasoning would make every (closed?) subset of a locally connected space again locally connected. That is clearly false (e.g.the Cantor set in $[0,1]$ shows that is false already). That should make you very suspicious of this indeed…..

Comment: The intersection of connected sets need not be connected at all..

Comment: You should add the definition of "locally connected" which you use.